# Validation in react

Tags: reactjs

I need your help. I'm trying to validate the input as well as do a search. I take data from JSON placeholder. I have the functionality that you can get the whole list, and you can get it separately, by id.
There are no errors in the console, but not everything works. When I try to get lists of posts, photos, albums, and posts, I do not see anything, but I wrote the logic of drawing elements to each of the endpoints. What is my mistake? Thank you very much

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

export let Inputs = () => {
    
    const Base_Url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    const availableResources = ['posts', 'comments', 'photos', 'albums', 'todos', 'users']
    
    const [endPoint, setEndpoint] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [singleItem, setSingleItem] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    
    const onSubmit = () => {
        if (!endPoint){
            return setError('First Input Is Required')
        }
    
        if (!availableResources.includes(endPoint)) {
            return setError('Value is not valid')
        }
    
        const idToNub = Number(id);
    
        if (!idToNub && id !== '') return
    
        fetchData()
        setError('')
    }
    
     const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${Base_Url}/${endPoint.trim()}/${id.trim()}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        if (id) {
            setSingleItem(data)
            setItems([])
            return
        }
        setSingleItem(null)
        setItems(data)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
             <input
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Type posts, comments, todos"
                 value={endPoint}
                 onChange={({target : {value}}) => setEndpoint(value)}
             />
             <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type id number"
                value={id}
                onChange={({target : {value}}) => setId(value)}
             />
             <button onClick={onSubmit}>Fetch Data</button>
             <pre>{singleItem && JSON.stringify(singleItem, null)}</pre>
             <h1>{error}</h1>
             {items.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el?.body}</div>)
                    
                  && items.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el?.title}</div>)
                  && items.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el?.name}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do you handle `item.mp` multiple times?

Comment: @Heartbit, In differents endpoints are different fields. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the fetched `data` is always an Array?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through your `items` once and check the values of each `item`:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

export let Inputs = () => {

    const Base_Url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    const availableResources = ['posts', 'comments', 'photos', 'albums', 'todos', 'users']

    const [endPoint, setEndpoint] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [singleItem, setSingleItem] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = () => {
        if (!endPoint){
            return setError('First Input Is Required')
        }

        if (!availableResources.includes(endPoint)) {
            return setError('Value is not valid')
        }

        const idToNub = Number(id);

        if (!idToNub && id !== '') return

        fetchData()
        setError('')
    }

     const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${Base_Url}/${endPoint.trim()}/${id.trim()}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        if (id) {
            setSingleItem(data)
            setItems([])
            return
        }
        setSingleItem(null)
        setItems(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>
             <input
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Type posts, comments, todos"
                 value={endPoint}
                 onChange={({target : {value}}) => setEndpoint(value)}
             />
             <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type id number"
                value={id}
                onChange={({target : {value}}) => setId(value)}
             />
             <button onClick={onSubmit}>Fetch Data</button>
             <pre>{singleItem && JSON.stringify(singleItem, null)}</pre>
             <h1>{error}</h1>
             {items.map(el => {
                const fields = Object.keys(el);
                let renderItems = fields.map(field => <div key={el[field]}>{el[field]}</div>)
                return renderItems;
              })
                    
              }
           </div>
      )
}
```